# Disable Focus - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

Is there any way to "disable" focus of an element (textarea, input, contentEditable iframe)?
I know the **blur** function takes away the focus, but the user can just go back and focus it again.

I'm asking this because there will be a point in my site where a sort of a prompt **(inside the page)** will ask for something. At this moment, I want to block the focus of all textareas and inputs in the page, and allow it again when the user press "Cancel" or "Ok".

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228114/with-jquery-how-can-i-gray-out-and-disable-a-webpage-and-then-show-some-kind-of might have your answer

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the user from focusing an `textarea` or `input` element, you can disable it:

```
$("#yourControlId").prop("disabled", true);
```

I'm not sure about a contentEditable iFrame