# background not accessible with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

1. I want to make whole background of web-page unclickable with some gray color behind
2. To pop some yes/no decision dialog on front
3. If yes is clicked then redirect to other page (same with no)

how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try googling "jQuery UI Dialog".  There's plenty of tutorials on this.

Here's a similar Stack Overflow Question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228114/with-jquery-how-can-i-gray-out-and-disable-a-webpage-and-then-show-some-kind-of)

I'm not sure how to grey out the background (it might even happen automagically with jQuery UI) but to create a new dialog box you need to include the jQuery UI library in your HTML page, include the style sheet too then it's a case of selecting a DOM element and calling the jQuery "dialog" function on it.  It would look something like this (note this is not working code):

```
<div id="dialog" title="my dialog">
    <p>Hello from the dialog</p>
</div>

<script>
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        // set  dialog properties here
    });
</script>
```

Here's a link to the jQuery dialog documentation: [http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

And here's a quick jsFiddle showing a dialog: [http://jsfiddle.net/wxKq5/7/](https://jsfiddle.net/wxKq5/7/)

I just checked and the jQuery UI modal dialog greys out the screen for you.  I've altered my jsFiddle code for you to show you how to instantiate one.